install SQL , PYSPARK on jupyter lab/Hub
I need your help, I am self learning.
I followed a link and created jupyter hub on GCP VM. The link: https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/google.html
I need to have an Icon of SQL and Pyspark, so I can use them and learn more.
Currently my screen look like

what i want is 
Thanks
I tried using chat gpt but didn't get a correct solution.
